# sql join query not returning data, just blank

Tags: sql, inner-join

I am trying to pull data from 2 separate tables but only specific columns, then I do a join so that only one row per client is displaying with the total sum of their payments but the information is not displaying. Code is below. It is for a reports page so think about geting the sum of all payments. I know what I am looking for, I just think that maybe there is a bug in the query that I can't seem to catch. I could use an extra pair of eyes to point out the flaw if possible. Thanks

```
SELECT   pre.id, pre.loanAmount, pre.custId, 
         SUM(pay.amount) AS amount, 
         DISTINCT(pay.company) AS company, 
         DISTINCT(pay.loanId) AS loanId
FROM preQualForm pre INNER JOIN
     payments pay
     ON pre.custId=pay.custId
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results.  As is, it's difficult to understand your question.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Feel free to add the tag for the database you are really using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DISTINCT` Keyword applies to all the columns you `SELECT`, 
so if you need to also do aggregate functions like `SUM`, 
then it is better achieved using a `GROUP BY` clause on non-aggregate columns.

The following should work.

```
SELECT   
    pre.id
    , pre.loanAmount
    , pre.custId
    , SUM(pay.amount) AS Amount
    , pay.company AS Company
    , pay.loanId AS LoanId
FROM preQualForm pre 
     INNER JOIN payments pay
     ON pre.custId = pay.custId
GROUP BY
    pre.id
    , pre.loanAmount
    , pre.custId
    , pay.company
    , pay.loanId
```

Comment: Thanks! I found a way to do it with portion of your example but I have a feeling I will need the rest of the group by real soon. I appreciate the Group By Example link!

Answer (score 0):

for starters you are Missing the `GROUP BY` clause. (There might be other issues but for that we need data and expected output)

```
SELECT pre.id, pre.loanAmount, pre.custId, SUM(pay.amount) AS amount,
       DISTINCT(pay.company) AS company, 
       DISTINCT(pay.loanId)  AS loanId
   FROM preQualForm pre
   INNER JOIN payments pay
   ON pre.custId=pay.custId
GROUP BY  pre.id, pre.loanAmount, pre.custId
```

Answer (score 0):

`DISTINCT()` is not a function in SQL (at least not in any dialect I am familiar with).  I would start with this query:

```
SELECT pre.custId, SUM(pay.amount) AS amount
FROM preQualForm pre INNER JOIN
     payments pay
     ON pre.custId = pay.custId
GROUP BY pre.custId;
```

It would seem to return what you want.  You can enhance it if this does not return all the information you really want.

Comment: SQL Server Does allow that usage of distinct. It just ignores the bracket.

Comment: @objectNotFound . . . SQL Server -- as with all databases -- supports `select distinct`.  No database supports `distinct()` as a function, nor `distinct` twice in the same `select`.

Comment: I was merely refering to using Distinct with brackets good catch on the invalid use of Two distincts in the same select.